# "Pusher chatkit onmessage hook is not responding in Reactjs app"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webhooks, react-hooks, chatkit

I am using pusher Chatkit to make a chat application in Reactjs. I have added the hooks property on onSubscribeRoomMultipart function with an onMessage Chatkit hook according to which it will print "received message, message" on console but it is not responding.

```
import React from 'react';
import CreateRoom from './components/CreateRoom';
import MessageList from './components/MessageList';
import RoomList from './components/RoomList';
import SendMessage from './components/SendMessage';
import { tokenUrl, instanceLocator } from './config';
import { ChatManager, TokenProvider } from '@pusher/chatkit-client'

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    const chatManager = new ChatManager({
      instanceLocator: instanceLocator,
      userId: 'Rajani',
      tokenProvider: new TokenProvider({ url: tokenUrl })
    })
  chatManager.connect()
  .then(currentUser => {
    console.log(currentUser);
    currentUser.subscribeToRoomMultipart({
      roomId: '21681554',
      hooks: {
        onMessage: message => {
          console.log("received message", message)
        }
      },
      messageLimit: 10
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error on connection', err)
  })

  }
  render(){
```